# How to explain stack space reservation in this simple C function?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I used gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6), with the optimization flag -O3 set to compile the following code:

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int d;
  int e;
};

int f(struct foo f);

int g() {
  struct foo x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  return f(x);
}
```

This is the assembly output I got:

```
    .file   "struct.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  g
    .type   g, @function
g:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $72, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 80
    movdqa  .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
    movl    $4, 16(%rsp)
    movups  %xmm0, (%rsp)
    call    f@PLT
    addq    $72, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   g, .-g
    .section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
    .align 16
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   1
    .long   2
    .long   3
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

What I don't know how to explain is, why did gcc reserve 72 bytes on the stack? It looks like the struct value {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} was moved to the area starting at %rsp and ending at %rsp+19, but what's with the extra 52 bytes?

Comment: Looks like missed optimization. clang does it with 24.

Comment: Well, part of it would be that the System V AMD64 ABI requires that the stack must be aligned to a 16 byte boundary on entering a function. So if `main`'s stack demands are solely for a 20 byte struct, then it would have to pad the stack expansion out to 32 bytes to ensure `f` is called with an appropriately aligned stack pointer. Not sure what the other 40 bytes would be for though.

Comment: @Jester: Is clang also inlining `f` in your test? Pretty sure if `f` isn't inlined, clang is required to use 32 bytes.

Comment: It's not inlining, hence the 24 bytes. The remaining 8 is for the return address.

Comment: @Jester: Ah, good point.

Comment: If you pass a struct as value it gets copied. So some space is needed for the argument. The local variable `x` will not accessible in `f()`.

Comment: I think 72 is for whole function g , not only for struct foo